# Change "if" statement based on variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

How can I change my "if" statement based a variable without writing a new statement for each case? My select dropdown "timeline" will be populated with 25+ options so I want to make the if statement in the php script

HTML to set variable:

```
<p>Current Status: </p> <select name="timeline" id="timeline">
            <option value="completed" selected>Completed</option>
            <option value="active">Active</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
     $current_state = $_POST['timeline'];
     $current = strtotime("now");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){




        if($current_state == "completed"){
             $end = strtotime($row['End']);

             $my_if = "if($current > $end){";

        }

        if($current_state == "active"){

           $end = strtotime($row['End']);
           $start = strtotime($row['Start']);

           $my_if = "if($start < $current && $end > $current){";

        }
                //THIS IS WHERE THE IF STATEMENT WOULD BE USED
                echo $my_if;

                            echo '<tr>
                            <td>'. $row['ID']  .'</td>
                            <td>'. $row['Name']  .'</td>
                            <td>'. $row['LastName']  .'</td>

                        </tr>';
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the conditions of your "meta-if" into the `if` itself:

```
if ($current_state == "completed")
    {
    $end = strtotime($row['End']);
    }

if ($current_state == "active")
    {
    $end = strtotime($row['End']);
    $start = strtotime($row['Start']);
    }

if (($current_state == "completed" && $current > $end) || ($current_state == "active" && $start < $current && $end > $current))
    {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>'. $row['ID']  .'</td>
    <td>'. $row['Name']  .'</td>
    <td>'. $row['LastName']  .'</td>
    </tr>';
    }
```

Comment: This is actually slower due to the extra if statements.

Comment: The slowndown from a couple of extra if-statements is neglible.

Comment: Especially compared to the IO done in `mysql_fetch_array()` for every time these `ifs` are interpreted.

Comment: @Zombaya - If you adopt the habit of assuming the trade-off is negligible, across a project containing thousands of lines of code your overall performance will suffer, it is poor programming practice to work this way.

Comment: @Geoffrey: You're optimizing prematurely. Surely your PHP application is not _that_ performance critical that you need to start worrying about a couple of `if` statements.

Comment: @CoreXii - My point is that it is a bad habit to form, and as shown in my answer, the optimized logic is shorter, less complex and easier to come back and re-read 6 months later. Remember that a PHP application may have to execute hundreds of times at the same time, that's when those additional if statements start stacking up. And yes, I have worked with PHP apps that were that critical for performance where simple fixes to the logic resolved major server load issues for my clients.

Comment: @Geoffrey I don't disagree with your refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

You should rework your logic completely

```
$completed = $_POST['timeline'] == 'completed';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $end = strtotime($row['End']);
    if (!$completed)
      $start = strtotime($row['Start']);

    if (
        ($completed  && $current > $end) ||
        (!$completed && $start < $current && $end > $current)
    ) {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```